# how to give nil parameter in if condition in swift?

Tags: swift, if-statement

In Objective-C:

```objc
if (!myImageView) {
    NSLog(@"hdhd");
}
else {
 //DO SOMETHING
}
```

But in Swift:

```swift
if (!myImageView) {  
   println("somethin")
}
else {
   println("somethin")
}
```

This code is giving me the error:

> Could not find an overload for '!' that accepts the supplied arguments'

`myImageView` is class variable `UIImageView`.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, the best way to deal with checking variables for `nil` in Swift is going to be with the `if let` or `if var` syntax.

```
if let imageView = self.imageView {
    // self.imageView is not nil
    // we can access it through imageView
} else {
    // self.imageView is nil
}
```

But for this to work (or for comparison against `nil` with either `== nil` or `!= nil`), `self.imageView` must be an optional (implicitly unwrapped or otherwise).

Non-optionals *can not* be `nil`, and therefore the compiler will not let you compare them against `nil`.  They'll never be `nil`.

So if `if let imageView = self.imageView` or `self.imageView != nil` or `self.imageView == nil` are giving you errors, it's almost certainly because `self.imageView` is not an optional.

Answer (score 1):

If your variable is of type `UIImageView` then it cannot ever be nil.
However if you want your code to be equivalent to your Objective-C code, change the variable type to `UIImageView?` (an optional type) and replace:

```
if (!myImageView) {
```

with:

```
if (myImageView == nil) {
```

Comment: If UIImageView can't be nil then how will I check??

Comment: That's the beauty of it, if it's declared as UIImageView you don't need to check for nil--the language guarantees that it won't be nil. For info on Swift optionals see here: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Answer (score 0):

Test for `myImageView != nil` or `myImageView.image != nil`.

Comment: myImageView != nil is is giving same error with '!=' in place of '!' but myImageView.image != nil is not giving error. but i don't want to put condition on image